# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a un js de un formulario html de inicio de sesión?

Tags: javascript, html, validación, login

**ESTE ES MI JS PARA VALIDAR LOS DATOS INGRESADO**

```js
function validar_datos()
{
    var n1,n2;
    n1 = document.getElementById("txtn1").value;
    n2 = document.getElementById("txtn2").value;
    
    if(n1==="" || n2===""){
        alert("Ingresa tu usuario y contraseña");
        return false;
    }else if(n1!=="admin" && n2!=="admin"){
        alert("Vuelva a Intentarlo");
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

HASTA EL MOMENTO TENGO EL LOGIN PERO QUISISERA PODER USAR EL JS PARA PODER VALIDAR AL USUARIO, ASIMISMO UNA VEZ SE PUEDA VALIDAR AL USUARIO PODER PASAR AL CONTROLADOR.
SEUN HE VISTO EN EL FORM SE PUEDE PONER ACTIOPN UNA VEZ INGRESADO PERO NO EJECUTA EL "CONTROLADOR", COMO PODRIA HAJCER QUE SE EJECUTO O COMO PODRIA LLAMARLO UNA VEZ SE VALIDE AL USUARIO"

**ESTE ES MI LOGIN**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/miestilo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="js/validar_datos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="container">
            
            <form >
            <h2>INICIAR SESION </h2>
            <input type="text" name ="txtn1" id="txtn1" placeholder="USUARIO">
            <br>
            <BR>
            <input type="text" name ="txtn2" id="txtn2" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA">
            
            <br></br>
            <div class="contenedor-botones">
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit" href="Controlador?accion=listar">INGRESAR</a>
          
            </div>
           
                
        </form>
            
            
        </div>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Estructura de paquetes]

Comment: primero que nada deberías observar el flujo de trabajo de tus archivos js y tu html, deberías dejar que cargue primero el html y luego incluir los archivos js en el html, esto te puede traer problemas a la hora de obtener referencias en el dom debido a que tu js se carga primero que tu html

Comment: para poder utilizar tu funcion `validar_datos` deberias obtener una referencia al elemento que ejecuta esa funcion, asi mismo como como obtienes los valores de los inputs

Comment: <script src="js/validar_datos.js" type="text/javascript"></script> esa seria mi referencia en el html

Comment: ok, pero la estas incluyendo antes de que cargue el body, deberias incluir el js al final del html, antes del `</body>`

Comment: <form action =""Controlador?accion=listar"" method="post" onsubmit="return validar_datos();" >   Nose si podria hacer algo asi? lo intente pero no me devuelve nada. o como podria colocarlo. soy nuevo en esto de webs :c

Comment: en el atributo `onSubmit` solamente agrega `validar_datos()`, esto causara que la pagina se actualice sola, puedes evitar esta accion con un simple, `event.preventDefault()` en la funcion `validar_datos`, el metodo `event` lo recives desde la misma funcion: `function validar_datos(event) {} `